# How to set size of image to match bootstrap thumbnail?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see, the right image is not fitted properly into my thumbnail

[image]

Whats weird is that both images are the exact same resolution (apparently from google images)

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
   <div class "container">
    <h1>In Your Shoes:<br> Make Connections Anonymously<br> </h1>
     <h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <%= image_tag("blank_avatar_male.jpg") %>
          </a>
         </div> 
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
           <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <%= image_tag("img_thing.jpeg") %>
           <a/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
           <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
           <%= image_tag("blank_avatar_female.jpg") %>
           </a>
          </div>
         </div> 
      </h2>
```

I know the html code doesnt look pretty, as I'm doing this myself.
I'm open to suggestions on how to improve it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out knowing the size of the images this is hard but this might help

```
 .thumbnail img {width:100px;height:100px}
```

just replace the 100px with the correct dimensions. that should make it uniform.

Comment: 300x300, sorry to add the info!

Comment: Just try this for 300px 

    .thumbnail img {width:300px;height:300px}

Comment: still a little space left =\. I think because since the background image color is grey, it shows it, whereas the other image background is white. Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use percent decryption for sizes, as follows:

```
.thumbnail img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Note that this won't respect the orignal image aspect ratio (it'll be stretched depending if either of the condition is not met: container.width/image.width==1 && container.height/image.height==1

You can do the following though to fix that: center the image horizontally while matching the height:

```
.thumbnail img {
    text-align: center;
    height:100%;
}
```

But then, you might probably see a seam on both side of the image, depending on colors.